# Show an OpenFileDialog and get the FileName property from it in one line

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I'm working on a simple application and I'm trying to get a shortcut to an exe that the user chooses. It's working as it is, but I was wondering if it's possible to open the dialog box and get the file path from it in one line so that I don't have to store the dialog box in memory.

I know it's possible to call multiple methods on one line, such as `string[] array = value.Trim().ToLower().Split('\\');` but when I try to do that type of setup with the OpenFileDialog, I get an error about the methods not existing.

Here's the code I have right now:

`OpenFileDialog box = new OpenFileDialog();
 box.ShowDialog();
 pathTextBox.Text = d.FileName;`

I was wondering if it would be possible (for neatness sake) to set it up something like `pathTextBox.Text = new OpenFileDialog().ShowDialog().FileName;`

Comment: The "store the dialog box in memory" part is not a problem. The memory it uses will be reclaimed automatically. It uses the same memory whether it appears on only one line or not.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm aware it'll be reclaimed quickly. I would just like to do this because the way it is now just looks messy to me.

Comment: Cramming everything into one line does not necessarily make the code "neat".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: it is called method call chaining. It works with `Trim().ToLower().Split()` because `Trim()` and `ToLower()` return `string`. You cannot chain call to `ShowDialog` this way, because `ShowDialog` method returns `DialogResult` which is just an `enum`.

However, in theory you could extract this to a separate extension method:

```
public static class OpenFileDialogExtensions
{
    public static string ShowDialogAndReturnFileName(this OpenFileDialog dialog)
    {
        // consider checking arguments
        dialog.ShowDialog(); 
        // consider checking the result of `ShowDialog` (e.g., user could close the dialog)
        return dialog.FileName;
    }
}

// Usage, just like you want:
pathTextBox.Text = new OpenFileDialog().ShowDialogAndReturnFileName();
```

Keep in mind that **shorter code doesn't mean better code**.
Perhaps, the best way to do this is not to do this.

Comment: The first paragraph in that actually answered my question, thanks. I didn't know that chain calling would be disallowed based on return type, but it does make sense.

Comment: @HoodedDeath I am glad it worked. One thing to mention: it's not like it is disallowed. Chaining assumes that you call a method (or extension method) on return type. So, `Trim()` returns `string`, so you can chain a call to `string`. `ToLower()` returns `string`, so you can chain a call to `string`. `Split()` returns an array, so you can chain a call to an array or `IEnumerable` next if you need. You would be able to chain a call with `ShowDialog` if you had to do something with its return type (`DialogResult`) or if it returned original dialog itself.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense when thinking about it that way. I hadn't thought about it in terms of what type was returned, I was more thinking about it in terms of 'run this function, ignore the result, and continue' but that makes no sense in terms of chaining ToLower and Trim. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly confident that none of the modal dialogs don't work that way.  While you *can* say:
`var foo = new OpenFileDialog().ShowDialog();`
The result of that is a `DialogResult`, and not the filename property you're looking for.  Additionally, you would no longer have a reference to the actual `FileDialog` object and could no longer extract the chosen filename anyway.
One alternative available to you is to make a method that makes it "look" like you're doing it with a single call:

```
public static string GetFilename()
{
    var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
    var filename = dlg.FileName;

    return filename;
}

public static void Main()
{
    var userChosenFile = GetFilename();
    var aDifferentChosenFile = GetFilename();
    var yetAnotherChosenFile = GetFilename();
}
```

Comment: An extension method like Yeldar's answer would also work.  It all really depends on how you want your code to look/read and if you have to do it a lot or not.